# Insert content as the first line a big file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a big file(10M - 30M records) line by line, performs some data manipulation to each line and writes to another file. I have a scenario where first line manipulation depends on some of the data on other lines and hence I can write the first line to the output file only after traversing through all other lines.

I have tried with `fileinput` like below:

```
with fileinput.input(temp_file_name, inplace=True) as file_inp:     
    for file_line in file_inp:         
        sys.stdout.write(file_line.replace('Header', f"{transformed_header_line}"))
```

Here, temp_file_name is the transformed file with first line as `Header` with all other transformed lines and using `fileinput` I am replacing string **Header** with new line and again writing to the file.
This process is taking time. Are there any other alternative methods like writing to stream of bytes or generator and later modify the data and write to the file.

Comment: Files are just streams of bytes. Unless the new first line is *exactly* the same length as the old first line, you will have to rewrite the entire rest of the file in order to make room for a longer first line or to fill in the gap left by a shorter new line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on ubuntu then you can use `sed` command in a subprocess as that is much faster.

```
subprocess.run(f"sed -i 's/Header/{transformed_header_line}/g' {temp_file_name}", shell=True)
```

Comment: Agree. Targeted use of os functions can speed up a lot.  I had a huge file where only some ranges of lines were of interest => `subprocess` `grep` to the rescue.  Huge saving over regexing in Python.  OP should perform all processing on file, close output and then, having seen all data, reswrite output header. Elegant, fast.